# Recursive file includes

Tags: awk

I'm writing an awk script to include sourced files in a shell script recursively:

```
$ cat build.awk 
function slurp(line) {
    if ( line ~ /^\. / || line ~ /^source / ) {
        split(line, words)
        while ( (getline _line < words[2]) > 0 ) {
            slurp(_line)
        }
    } else if ( NR != 1 && line ~ /^#!/ ) {
        # Ignore shebang not in the first line
    } else {
        print line
    }
}

{
    slurp($0)
}
```

For example, with the following four shell scripts,

```
$ for i in a b c d; do cat $i.sh; echo; done
#!/bin/sh
echo this is a
. b.sh

#!/bin/sh
echo this is b
. c.sh
. d.sh

#!/bin/sh
echo this is c

#!/bin/sh
echo this is d
```

I expect that by running `awk -f build.awk a.sh` I get

```
#!/bin/sh
echo this is a
echo this is b
echo this is c
echo this is d
```

However, the actual result is

```
#!/bin/sh
echo this is a
echo this is b
echo this is c
```

**d.sh is not included.** How can I fix this? What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, that was because in awk, variables have no lexical scope! I am too noob for the awk language. The following works:

```
$ cat build.awk 
function slurp(line,    words) {
    if ( line ~ /^\. / || line ~ /^source / ) {
        split(line, words)
        while ( (getline _line < words[2]) > 0 ) {
            slurp(_line)
        }
    } else if ( NR != 1 && line ~ /^#!/ ) {
        # Ignore shebang not in the first line
    } else {
        print line
    }
}

{
    slurp($0)
}

$ awk -f build.awk a.sh 
#!/bin/sh
echo this is a
echo this is b
echo this is c
echo this is d
```